# Sending a file over a request, so that the browser downloads the file

Tags: moqui

I have successfully generated an XML file using FTL template. Thanks to Debmalya Biswas and his code.

The code saves the file (with specified name) to a set directory on the drive. But I would like to have the file (sorry for the description) handed over by a request, so that the browser saves the file to its download location. Could you please help?

```
<transition name="generateSEPAXML2">
    <actions>
        <script>
            <![CDATA[
                        import java.io.*

                        def screenRenderer = ec.screen.makeRender().rootScreen("component://SimpleScreens/screen/SimpleScreens/Accounting/Payment/PaymentSEPA.xml")
                                        .webappName("webroot").renderMode("csv")

                        String renderOutput = screenRenderer.render()

                        String fileName = "platba_" + paymentId + "_SEPA.xml"

                        Writer writer = new FileWriter(fileName)
                        writer.write(renderOutput)
                        writer.close()
            ]]>
        </script>
        <!--<service-call name="update#mantle.account.payment.Payment" in-map="[paymentId:paymentId, statusId:'PmntConfirmed']"/>-->
    </actions>

    <default-response url="."/>
</transition>
```

Answer (score 1):

For those seeking an answer, this worked for me:

```
    <transition name="generateSEPAXML3">
    <actions>
        <script>
            <![CDATA[
                        import java.io.*

                        def screenRenderer = ec.screen.makeRender().rootScreen("component://SimpleScreens/screen/SimpleScreens/Accounting/Payment/PaymentSEPA.xml")
                                        .webappName("webroot").renderMode("csv")

                        String renderOutput = screenRenderer.render()
                        ec.web.sendTextResponse(renderOutput, "text/xml", "platba_" + paymentId + "_SEPA.xml")
            ]]>
        </script>
        <!--<service-call name="update#mantle.account.payment.Payment" in-map="[paymentId:paymentId, statusId:'PmntConfirmed']"/>-->
    </actions>

    <default-response type="none"/>
</transition>
```

I used the sendTextResponse method of ExecutionContext WebFacade.